# What SQL 2000 rights are required for creating SQL Agent jobs?

Tags: security, sql-server-2000, sql-server-agent

It's been a long while since I looked at SQL Jobs on SQL Server 2000.

On SQL 2005, if I want to allow a user to create jobs etc I add the requisite login to msdb and assign one of the roles SQLAgentUserRole, SQLAgentReaderRole or SQLAgentOperatorsRole role. No problem there.

Perhaps someone can help me jog my memory about rights/roles required to create jobs on SQL 2000 because I'm embarassed to say that I've completely forgotten and SQL 2000 books online aren't terribly clear.

If a user is dbo in a SQL 2000 database, does that automatically grant rights to create sql agent jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, every user can create a new SQL Server Agent job.

What you have control on is their rights on your Database objects.  I just tried it and a user with no rights at all (denydatareader and denydatawriter on all databases) can still create a new SQL Server Agent job but he can't do anything inside it.

Hope this helps!